# NullPointerException For FindById

Tags: spring

Can't seem to get FindById working in my project. It keeps giving the same error no matter what i try, it might be just something small but can't figure it out.

edit: added configbean.xml

```
RowMapper
public class CustDetailsRowMapper implements RowMapper<CustDetails> {

     CustDetails CustDetails;
    @Override
    public CustDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

         CustDetails.setCustName(rs.getString("CUSTNAME"));
         CustDetails.setAddress(rs.getString("CUSTADDRESS"));
         CustDetails.setCustId(rs.getInt("CUSTID"));
        return CustDetails;
    }
```

DAO code:

```
@Repository 
public class CustDetailsDaoImplementation implements CustDetailsDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 

    @Override
    public CustDetails findById(int custId) {
        String sql = "Select * FROM CUSTOMERDETAILS WHERE CUSTID = ?";
        CustDetails custDetails = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new CustDetailsRowMapper(), custId);
        return custDetails;
    }
```

Service code:

```
   public class CustDetailsServiceImplementation implements custDetailsService {
      @Autowired
      CustDetailsDAO custDetailsDAO;

    @Override
    public List<CustDetails> getAllCusts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<CustDetails>) custDetailsDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public CustDetails getACustByItsId(int custId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return custDetailsDAO.findById(custId);
    }
```

MainApp:

```
public class MainApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("configBean.xml");

       custDetailsService CustDetailsService  = (custDetailsService) context.getBean("custDetailsServiceImplementation");
       System.out.println(CustDetailsService.getACustByItsId(1));

  }
```

Can't seem to fix this error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ie.sean.dao.CustDetailsDaoImplementation.findById(CustDetailsDaoImplementation.java:26)
    at ie.sean.services.CustDetailsServiceImplementation.getACustByItsId(CustDetailsServiceImplementation.java:26)
    at ie.sean.domain.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
```

configBean.xml code:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="ie.sean" />

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<bean id="JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"  autowire="byType" />

</beans>
```

Comment: looks like `custDetailsDAO` is `null` ?

Comment: Can you share your configBean.xml file?

Comment: You have to either Autowire or initialize:: 
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
  ::: in CustDetailsDaoImplementation.java

Comment: I autowire the JdbcTemplate and it gives me a differnt null pointer in rowmapper for this line CustDetails.setCustName(rs.getString("CUSTNAME"));

Comment: Also, your mapper must create a new CustDetails for each row. Otherwise, you'll have N references to a unique CustDetails object.

Comment: @WhoIsThis You need to initialize `CustDetails CustDetails = new CustDetails();` in first line of `maprow` method

Comment: aaaa thank you somehow forgot the new CustDetails, it works now

Comment: @WhoIsThis you're welcome. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it as soon as possible. It will help you a lot